# Why doesn’t Everett react to Big Dan’s beating?

Tags: plot-explanation, o-brother-where-art-thou

In “[O brother, where art thou?](http://imdb.com/title/tt0190590/)” (2000), there’s a scene in which Big Dan (John Goodman) starts teaching Everett (George Clooney) and Delmar (Tim Blake) a lesson and ends up beating them mercilessly:

While Delmar defends Everett and himself, Everett does nothing. While I get that he is knocked out after a big hit, before that, his trip companion is being hit once and again and it seems obvious he is next, but he just sits there smiling and doing nothing. Why is that?

Comment: Would you accept that it's simply that Everett is an idiot?

Comment: That actually may be a good answer. I thought it could be lack of empathy towards Delmar (or anyone for that matter), as Everett doesn't seem to care for/about anyone that is not himself. But still...

Comment: The lack of empathy probably contributes, too - we see evidence of both traits throughout the movie - but here, I think, the idiocy is the prime factor as he is simply politely listening to Big Dan's "lesson". I'd have to watch the movie again to build a good answer, though.

Comment: It's not enough for an answer, but O Brother is based on the Odyssey. In the Odyssey, Odysseus also watches the cyclops attack (and eat) some of his crewman.